# template rendering works fine but when I use template inheritance it displays error

Tags: django, templates, include

I tried the using {% include 'navbar.html'%}  on room.html template both of them work fine and display the template but when I add {% include 'navbar.html'%} in room.html try to render it displays this error
I adjust have also include the templates in the setting what seems to be the problem.
**The urls file in first app is**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns =[
path('',views.home),
path('room/',views.room),
path('navbar/',views.navbar),
```

**and the views file is like this**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
def home(request):
 return render(request,'firstapp/home.html')
def room(request):
 return render(request,'firstapp/room.html')
def navbar(request):
 return render(request,'firstapp/navbar.html')    
def main(request):
 return render(request,'main.html') 

   images of error displayed in Django and setting file
```

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/MH8fL.png  error displayed in Django

[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wh8Ot.png   error displayed in Django
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/phUt0.png  settings file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome at SO! Don't post code/errors in pictures. Help community help you :)

You probably need to use:

```
{% include 'firstapp/navbar.html' %}
```

Comment: You are right, and also i think it must be `'DIRS': [BASE_DIR / 'templates']` rather than `'DIRS': [BASE_DIR , 'templates']`, so that server can reload automatically after saving changes.

Comment: Actually you don't have to put anything there. Django check `templates` folders by default.

Comment: The thing you said is relevant when you make inner `templates` folder, but if you make single templates folder for all the apps outside then we have to mention it as I suggested above.

Comment: I don't think that's good idea, but yeah, that's true.

Comment: thanks a lot Nixon   {% include 'firstapp/navbar.html' %}   fixed the error